# Azure Auto scaling Dependency on virtual scale set and its limitation

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, autoscaling

In Azure why there is not auto scaling for invidual virtual machine. Auto scaling is done through virtual scale set which supports hand full of operating system images. Is there is any limitation of VSS vs virtual machines. Is there is any way to do auto scaling for virtual machine other than using this 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2015/02/20/autoscaling-azurevirtual-machines/

I think azure monitor can be configured for to autoscale a VM but I could not figure out how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Classic VM supports autoscaling. Azure classic VM is behind a Load balance. But Azure ARM VM does not support this feature.

If you really want to use this, you could create a metric alert, when your VM reach this alert you could execute a runbook. In this runbook, you could use Azure Power Shell to resize VM.

**Note: However, it is really not recommend you do this. Because when you resize this VM, your VM will restart and your VM could not provide service. The restarting time maybe take up to a few minutes. This is disastrous for your service. If possible, I suggest you could use VMSS.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Another solution is that create two VMs and a load balancer. The two VMs are behind the load balancer. You could resize a VM, service is not interrupted.

Comment: @BlindSniper Hi, could you share you need more detail? I think I could help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Machine Scale Sets (VMSS) is used for deploying highly available infrastructure where a set of machines have similar set-up. That’s also where you’d most likely use Autoscaling for VM resources. Therefore, currently, you can use Azure Autoscale to automatically scale a scale set but not individual VMs. You might want to leave some [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216843-virtual-machines) on this here.

Refer [Get started with auto scale by custom metric in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-autoscale-scale-by-custom-metric) to know more about how you can use Azure Monitor Autoscale feature for VMSS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how do you expect to scale a regular vm? Sure Azure could créate an empty vm for you? how good is that? no good. So there's generally no easy way to autoscale vms, because you need to configure them before using.

You could use custom solutions (like the one you've linked) to achieve scaling.